# How to send message to all terminals using C (Linux)?

Tags: c, linux, echo

I'm trying to send message to all terminals for my user.

```
echo -e "\nHello" > /dev/pts/1
```

works fine, but

```
echo -e "\nHello" > /dev/pts/*
```

doesn't work

[image]

And I need to realize it via C code.

like that:

```
if(fork() == 0){
            execl("echo -e '\nHello' > /dev/pts/*", NULL);
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: does the `wall` command do what you need?

Comment: I still do not understand how to display a message on a neighboring terminal using `wall`, it sends on CLI terminals (using Alt+Ctrl+F1)

Comment: @ChristianGibbons doesn't `wall` send to all _users_, not _terminals_?

Comment: @svstnv When I open up a dozen terminals under one user and execute `wall`, it prints to all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use a bash loop :

```
for f in /dev/pts/*; do echo -e "\nHello" > $f; done
```

Also, you should use "system" to call a shell command.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
void main(void) {
    system("for f in /dev/pts/*; do echo -e '\nHello' > $f; done");
}
```

Comment: Consider using system instead of execl, I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: As said above, you could use `wall` but it doesn't seem to work with all GUI terminals. More info [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/789510/wall-doesnt-broadcast-to-gui-terminals-on-16-04)